# Getting error while running sonar scanner for ts project

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I am running sonar analysis for a ts project. But getting below error during analysis. Please let me know as what is causing the issue ?

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 31.904s
INFO: Final Memory: 11M/262M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to highlight file src/app/Footer/Download/download.component.spec.ts
ERROR: Caused by: 3 is not a valid line for pointer. File src/app/Footer/Download/download.component.spec.ts has 1 line(s)

Comment: Can you post code for `download.component.spec.ts ` file

Comment: first few lines

Comment: import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FooterDownloadComponent } from './download.component';

describe('FooterDownloadComponent', () => {
  let component: FooterDownloadComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooterDownloadComponent>;